# menu links aligment not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 navbar. But on one of my drop downs I have add a `<span class="label label-success"></span>`

I cannot seem to get my `span` inline with the links that it is connected to. Not sure what to do.

Demo here: Click on the notices link for drop down menu. http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/asqoy

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 280px;
}

ul.nav .navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #222222;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-menu li a span {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKJHp

```
.dropdown-menu li a span {
    float: right;
    line-height: inherit; /** set the line-height to inherit */
}
```

Comment: did not do any thing still pushes span down.

Comment: I did and it not the span labels are not inline with the text.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some advice else where. It now works by using this css

```
ul.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}   

ul.dropdown-menu span.label {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```